# Try to figure out what is it

Tags: riddle

> If you don't have one
>   You wish to not have one.
>   But if you have one,
>   You wish to not lose it.

What is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is:

> A lawsuit
>
>  Self explanatory really... Nobody wants a lawsuit, but if you have one then you don't want to lose

Comment: Bravo! that's great!

Answer (score 7):

The answer can be:

> A fight

Because

> You don't want to fight, but if you're having a fight you don't want to lose.

Comment: Hmm it's a good answer but not the one I was thinking about.

Comment: This is essentially the same as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the answer is :

> Temper

If you don't have one
You wish to not have one.

> You don't want to have a temper!

But if you have one,
you wish to not loosing it.

> If you have temper, then you try not to lose it!

Comment: No not the answer

Answer (score 2):

Can it be

> Glasses/ spectacles

1. > If a person does not wear glasses he wishes his eyes work perfectly for ever so that he never has to wear glasses
2. > But if he gets one because of bad sight he wishes he never looses them because without them he can't see , basically he can't do anything